# Bypassing a requiredfieldvalidator

Tags: asp.net

I have a webform which has validators on it that work well when the user presses the submit button. But when the user presses the logout button the validators stop that button from working.

Any suggestions as to how remedy this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `CausesValidation` property on the button.

```
<asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server"
  Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="False">
</asp:Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have ValidationGroup set up?

Comment: No, I don't know what that is. I'm really new to .net.

Answer (score 0):

Validation Groups shouldn't be needed.  Instead, you need to specify on your buttons that they do not cause validation.  This means you set the `CausesValidation` property to false.

At that point, that control's events won't trigger validation (client or server side).